# What are the various types of protein-protein interactions

Tags: proteins

I understand there are a number of protein-protein interactions, but what types of interactions exist? and what are the characteristics of them?

Comment: Characteristics? They happen between proteins.

Comment: characteristics of the interaction type, i.e, what makes a hydrophobic interaction?

Comment: I would suggest asking "what are the various types of protein-protein interactions"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many types of protein-protein interactions via various domains, such as SH2 binding (in RTK signaling), Pleckstrin Homology domain (involved in signaling) among others. This site gives a nice list: http://pawsonlab.mshri.on.ca/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=30&Itemid=63

Of course, protein-protein interactions rely on the premises of basic biochemistry:

- van-der waals interactions (at the most basic level)
- Electrostatic interactions
- "Lock and Key" model: Some proteins have specific binding pockets for domains of other proteins
- Induced fit

There are many ways to study protein-protein interactions, including, but not limited to

- Pull-down assays
- 2D SDS-PAGE / MS
- Yeast two-hybrid
- Immunoprecipitation

Comment: jp has a good point - technically there is no 'hydrophobic force' but when computations are done, a hydrophobic term is often made in the calculations.

Comment: Although hydrophobicity isn't a "force", shouldn't it still be included in the answer (creates an entropic advantage)?